# Splitting an array into 2 smaller arrays of 80% and 20% size of the original?

Tags: java

I have an array of X length, and I'd like to be able to split it into two smaller arrays. One with 80% of the length of the original and one with 20% length.

So an array of length 10 would split into two smaller arrays of length 8 and 2.

I have the code below which I believe should work, but when I run the code using an array of length 7 the trainingSize variable is set to 0.0, and therefore the testingSet variable is then set to 7.0. Why is this? Is this just an error with the console and not the actual code?

```
        int size = array.length;
        float trainingSize = (float) (size/100);
        System.out.println(size/100);
        float testingSize = size - trainingSize;

        System.out.println("\nSize: " + size);
        System.out.println("Training set size: " + trainingSize);
        System.out.println("Testing set size: " + testingSize);
```

Comment: You can use integer division to get whole index numbers. **But shouldn't you be getting a random split for train/test**?

Comment: don't you need to do float trainingSize = size * 80.0f /100.0f; ??

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int size = array.length;;
int trainingSize = (int)(size * 0.8);
int testingSize = size - trainingSize;
```

Firstly multiplier for 80%  should be 0.8
And for array index its better  to cast it back to int

Answer (score 0):

`size/100` is an integer. 
So you need to change the division to be a float- division. You can du this by making one of the factors a flat.

```
float trainingSize = size/100.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

```
    int size = array.length;
    float percent = 80.0f;
    int trainingSize = (int)(size * (percent / 100));// size = 5
    int testingSize = size - trainingSize;           // size = 2
```

---

**Full example using Java 10**

```
    var array = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    var size = array.length;
    var percent = 80.0f;
    var trainingSize = (int) (size * (percent / 100));// size = 5
    //var testingSize = size - trainingSize;           // size = 2 (No need to)

    var array1 = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i < trainingSize, i -> i + 1).map(i -> array[i])
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);

    var array2 = Stream.iterate(trainingSize, i -> i < size, i -> i + 1).map(i -> array[i])
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7]
```

Comment: if all you want to do is split the list you can use List<>. subList() and calculate the indices why do the streaming and mapping.

Comment: @mavriksc I just try to learn the new features of Java 10 that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

to ernest's point

*edit* this is actually more effecient.. only randomly pulls the test data

```
    List<Object> things = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> train = new ArrayList<>();
    int sampSize = things.size() / 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < sampSize; i++) {
        test.add(things.remove(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(things.size())));
    }
    train.addAll(things);
```